# Trouble with saving data to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I've got a useEffect that sets state.user, which allows me to persist state and keep a user logged in as they navigate around.  Auth.currentSession and Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser (line 105-106) are part of the AWS Amplify library and basically pull from localStorage (which I just learned about yesterday).  So useEffect runs, calls the dispatch on line 110.  line 115 prints the returned data from Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser, but 116 prints something equivalent to initialState when I expect to see values equivalent to "user" because "user" is sent as payload with the dispatch to "LOGIN".  I'm guessing the "[ ]" argument in the useEffect has something to do with it, but I can't figure out what value to put in there to keep it from going into an infinite loop.  My main goal is to save data to state and use it in other components with useContext.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import MainNavbar from './components/Navbar';
import Home from './components/Home';
import LogIn from './components/auth/LogIn';
// import Register from './components/auth/Register';
import ForgotPassword from './components/auth/ForgotPassword';
import ForgotPasswordVerification from './components/auth/ForgotPasswordVerification';
import ChangePassword from './components/auth/ChangePassword';
import ChangePasswordConfirm from './components/auth/ChangePasswordConfirm';
// import Welcome from './components/auth/Welcome';
// import Ingredients from './components/Ingredients';
import Recipes from './components/Recipes';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
// import axios from 'axios';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { faCheckSquare, faCoffee, faEdit } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

library.add( faCheckSquare, faCoffee, faEdit);

// const config = require('./config.json');

export const AuthContext = React.createContext();
const initialState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  // isAuthenticating: true,
  user: null,
  userSettings: null, 
  userRec: null,
  userIng: null, 
  userData: null,
  defaultIng: null
}
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOGIN":
      console.log("LOGIN");
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        user: action.payload
      };
    case "LOGOUT":
      console.log("LOGOUT");
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        user: null
      };
    case "INITIALIZE_USER_DATA":
      const userId = state.user.attributes.sub;
      console.log(state.user);
      let userRec = [];
      let userIng = [];
      let userData = [];
      let defaultIng = [];
      async function initializeUserData() {
        try {
          const params = {
            "userId": userId,
            "sett": true
          };
          let res1 = await axios.patch(`${config.api.invokeUrl}/user/configsettings`, params);
          let res2 = await axios.post(`${config.api.invokeUrl}/recipes/${userId}`, params);
          let res3 = await axios.get(`${config.api.invokeUrl}/ingredients`);
          console.log(res1);
          console.log(res2);
          console.log(res3);
          defaultIng = res3.data.sort((a, b) => (a.iName > b.iName) ? 1 : -1);
          // this.setUserSettings(res1.data.Attributes);  //4-13-2020, Myles - seems to be the same data coming from res2 and assigned to userData.
          let arr1 = res2.data;
          arr1.forEach( item => {
            if (item.sk.startsWith("USER-")) {
              userData.push(item);
            } else if (item.sk.startsWith("REC-")) {
              userRec.push(item);
            } else if (item.sk.startsWith("ING-")) {
              userIng.push(item);
            }
          });
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      }
      initializeUserData();
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        user: action.payload,
        userRec: userRec,
        userIng: userIng,
        userData: userData,
        defaultIng: defaultIng
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  async function authStatus() {
    try {
      let session = await Auth.currentSession();
      let user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
      console.log(user);
      console.log(session);
      if (session && user) {
        dispatch({
          type: "LOGIN",
          payload: user
        });
      };
      console.log(user);
      console.log(state);
    }catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    authStatus();
  },[]);
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        state,
        dispatch
      }}
    >
      <div className="App">
        <Router>
          <div className="container">
            <MainNavbar />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component = {Home} />
              <Route exact path="/login" render={() => <LogIn />} />
              <Route exact path="/recipes" render={() => <Recipes />} />
              <Route exact path="/forgotpassword" render={() => <ForgotPassword />} />
              <Route exact path="/forgotpasswordverification" render={() => <ForgotPasswordVerification />} />
              <Route exact path="/changepassword" render={() => <ChangePassword />} />
              <Route exact path="/changepasswordconfirmation" render={() => <ChangePasswordConfirm />} />
            </Switch>
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: setting state is an asynchronous process, you cannot log the value right below setting it

Answer (score 0):

> I'm guessing the `[]` argument in the `useEffect` has something to do with it **(state is always initialState)**, but I can't figure out what `value` to put in there to keep it from going into an infinite loop!!
>
> **A common question that taunts many of us when using the famous `useEffect` hook.** Indeed, the `useEffect` has something to do with your `state` updates, if any side effects actually change your `state`.
>
> **Note:** If you pass an empty array `[]`, the **props** and **state** inside the effect will always have their initial values.

**Quick solution:** (+)

- Either add `state` to the `useEffect` dependency array
- or `console.log(state)` within the `return()` statement

```js
// summarized version, to focus on issue at hand
function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  
  // invoked within the useEffect()
  async function authStatus() {
    try {
      let session = await Auth.currentSession();
      let user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
      if (session && user) { dispatch({ type: "LOGIN", payload: user }) };
      console.log(user);
      console.log(state); // thus, this is always initialState (see useEffect() below)
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    authStatus();
    // If you pass an empty array ([]), the props and state 
    // inside the effect will always have their initial values.
- }, []);
    // Either, refactor the dependency array to include "state"
+ }, [state]);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      <div className="App">
+       {console.log(state)} // Or, log "state" here
        <Router>{/* Routes */}</Router>
      </div>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**Here's a detailed explanation:**
Credit to the [React team who did a good job to explain the useEffect()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) and it's effects:)

- Note that by default, `useEffect` runs both after the first `render` and after every update. Sometimes you don't want the `useEffect` to always run after `render`.
  How do I make that happen?
- Thus to optimize performance, you can skip effects by passing an `array []` as an **optional second argument** to `useEffect`. Again, the React team recommends using the [exhaustive-deps rule](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920) as part of the [eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks#installation) package. It warns when dependencies are specified incorrectly and suggests a fix. Note, this is included, by default, if you use [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started).
- If you use this optimization (mentioned above), make sure the array includes all values from the component scope (such as props and state) that change over time and that are used by the effect. Otherwise, your code will reference stale values from previous renders. That's why if you `console.log()` here, **props** and **state** will always have their initial values.